# Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

While I try to run this code, I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '='

Can you please help me to correct this error.

```
String sDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    DateTime datevalue = (Convert.ToDateTime(sDate.ToString()));
    String dy = datevalue.Day.ToString();
    int mn = datevalue.Month;
    int yy = datevalue.Year;

var debit = _dbConnect.GetOneData("SELECT SUM(debit) FROM [sem_db].[dbo].[ledger] WHERE h_id = '9' & entry_date.Value.Month = 'mn' && entry_date.Value.Year = 'yy'");
public class DbConnect
{
    readonly SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection();

    private void GetConnection()
    {
        _con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sem_dbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        _con.Open();
        return;
    }

    public object GetOneData(string query)
    {
        GetConnection();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _con);
        var val = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); ------------>(error comes here)
        _con.Close();
        return val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In sql and operator is 'and' not '&&'
Assuming you are usinc C# code
Change

```
var debit = _dbConnect.GetOneData("SELECT SUM(debit) FROM [sem_db].[dbo].[ledger] WHERE h_id = '9' & entry_date.Value.Month = 'mn' && entry_date.Value.Year = 'yy'")
```

to

```
var debit = _dbConnect.GetOneData("SELECT SUM(debit) FROM [sem_db].[dbo].[ledger] WHERE h_id = '9' and [ledger].Month = '"+mn+"' and [ledger].Year = '"+yy+"'")
```

try to use parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection

Comment: TnKs sir, But another error occurs. Can you help me to solve this too.. the error is "The multi-part identifier "entry_date.Value.Month" could not be bound"

Comment: @RenjithStephen edited answer..hope `year` and `month` are database column name in `ledger` table

Comment: No, there is only one field named "entry_date". And i'm trying to calculate the debit sum of the customer with h_id 9

Comment: @RenjithStephen then  your query is wrong how can you write a condition for a column not existing for a table..you are missing some table and joins

Comment: i just try to do like this. "select sum(l.credit) as debit ,sum(l.debit) as credit  from ledger as l inner join head as h on l.h_id=h.h_id where line='1' and month(l.entry_date)=month(getdate()) and year(l.entry_date)=year(getdate()) "

Answer (score 1):

```
var debit = _dbConnect.GetOneData("SELECT SUM(debit) FROM [sem_db].[dbo].[ledger] WHERE h_id = '9' & entry_date.Value.Month = 'mn' && entry_date.Value.Year = 'yy'")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var debit = _dbConnect.GetData_DataTable("select (sum(debit)-sum(credit)) as openingBalance from ledger where h_id='9' and cast( entry_date as date)< CAST( dateadd(MONTH ,-1, GETDATE())as date)");
```

Comment: You should add **at least** a sentence of two to **explain** what you did, and why. Just dumping a huge long line of code *without* any explanation isn't very helpful ....

Comment: String sDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    DateTime datevalue = (Convert.ToDateTime(sDate.ToString()));
    String dy = datevalue.Day.ToString();
    int mn = datevalue.Month;
    int yy = datevalue.Year;

Comment: these are not needed instead of that i take the date values using getdate() in the query. var debit = _dbConnect.GetData_DataTable("select (sum(debit)-sum(credit)) as openingBalance from ledger where h_id='9' and cast( entry_date as date)< CAST( dateadd(MONTH ,-1, GETDATE())as date)");

Comment: You should put this **into your response** - not here in comments..... **edit** your response, please!